# Adding title text with variable to form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm using jQuery UI Tooltips in Rails to provide tooltips on a form. The text in the tooltip is provided by the title field. What I'm trying to doing is:

```
<%= f.text_field :member_number, :class => "ui-tooltip", 
:title => "A membership is required to participate at" @event_name %>
```

I know this isn't the right way add the variable, but can't for the life of me figure out the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach is to use Ruby string interpolation:

```
:title => "A membership is required to participate at #{@event_name}"
```

It would also have worked to use string concatenation:

```
:title => "A membership is required to participate at" + @event_name
```

(Both of these would be inside the `<%` `%>` tags, of course, as you had already done.)